# ggplot2: add line for average per group

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

orderX <- c("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3)
y <- rnorm(20)
x <- as.character(1:20)
group <- c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 7), rep("C", 5), rep("A", 3))
df <- data.frame(x, y, group)
df$lvls <- as.numeric(orderX[df$group])

ggplot(data = df, aes(x=reorder(df$x, df$lvls), y=y)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = group)) + 
geom_line(stat = "hline", yintercept = "mean", aes(colour = group))
```

I want to create a graph like this:
[image: graph with averages for each group]

This does work, when I do not need to reorder the values of X, however, when I do use reorder, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I think your use of reorder is mistaken here, since it will just reorder X, not groups or Y.  This will plot the wrong x with the wrong y!

Comment: Unless X doesn't mean anything but index, in which case, don't use it in the plot (use jitter instead?)

Comment: Then my use of reorder is mistaken. In my real data the values on x are labels for each individual measurement, which I do want to see. The ordering of these labels within the groups does not matter.

Comment: Maybe another reason why it does not work in my case is, because my x-values are not numeric, but character.

Comment: +1 for a concise question, with sample data and a picture.  I'd give +1 for each of those if I could.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of ggplot2 2.x this approach is unfortunately broken.

The following code provides exactly what I wanted, with some extra calculations up front:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

orderX <- c("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3)
y <- rnorm(20)
x <- as.character(1:20)
group <- c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 7), rep("C", 5), rep("A", 3))
dt <- data.table(x, y, group)
dt[, lvls := as.numeric(orderX[group])]
dt[, average := mean(y), by = group]
dt[, x := reorder(x, lvls)]
dt[, xbegin := names(which(attr(dt$x, "scores") == unique(lvls)))[1], by = group]
dt[, xend := names(which(attr(dt$x, "scores") == unique(lvls)))[length(x)], by = group]

ggplot(data = dt, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour = group)) +
    facet_grid(.~group,space="free",scales="free_x") + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = xbegin, xend = xend, y = average, yend = average, group = group, colour = group))
```

The resulting image:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will help in your exact situation, but the new solution I found with ggplot2 v2.1.0 for a similar problem is `stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", fun.ymin = "mean", fun.ymax= "mean", size= 0.3, geom = "crossbar")`.

Comment: I tried that, that creates horizontal lines per item on the x-axis. The reason for that is, that the x-axis is discrete.

Answer (score 18):

From your question, I don't this `df$x` is relevant to your data at all, especially if you can re-order it.  How about just using `group` as x, and `jitter` the actual x position to separate the points:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=group,y=y,color=group)) + geom_point() +
geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.4)) +
geom_errorbar(stat = "hline", yintercept = "mean",
  width=0.8,aes(ymax=..y..,ymin=..y..))
```

I have used errorbar instead of h_line (and collapsed the ymax and ymin to y) since hline is complex.  If anyone has a better solution to that part, I'd love to see.

[image]

---

**update**

If you want to preserve the order of X, try this solution (with modified X)

```
df$x = factor(df$x)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, group=group)) + 
facet_grid(.~group,space="free",scales="free_x") + 
geom_point() + 
geom_line(stat = "hline", yintercept = "mean")
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed almost what I want, however, I do want to be able to see the original x-values on the x-scale.

Comment: When you do the re-order above, your data gets mixed up.  You should sort on the original data frame, not just the x values.  Do you want the x values interleaved in your chart?  If they are, where do you want to place the mean values?

Comment: where did you find the documentation on geom_line(stat="hline", yintercept="mean")?  That's really cool and I haven't seen it before.

Comment: I actually can't remember, will look it up tomorrow on my machina at work. Must be somewhere in the browser history. :)

Comment: This is were I found that: http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-3/

Comment: I have run your code and the `geom_line` for the mean give me this error:`Error in tapply(1:nrow(data), splitv, list) : 
  arguments must have same length`. Any idea what I have done wrong?. Also why in the question `x` is `as char` this make the x in the faceting get alphabetically sorted `1 10 ..2 20 ..`