# Add average lines for categorical scatterplots with single group values

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have a categorical scatter plot like this:

[image]

which I generated in R with the following code (using the ggplot2 library):

```
data <- runif(50, 13, 17)
factors <- as.factor(sample(1:3, 50, replace = TRUE))
groups <- as.factor(sample(1:3, 50, replace = TRUE))
data_table <- data.frame(data, factors)
g <- ggplot(data_table, aes(y = data_table[, 1], x = data_table[, 2], colour = groups)) + geom_point(size = 1.5)
```

I am trying to add an average line for each x-group, but I can't manage to find the right way. I have already tried with the procedure described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244157/ggplot2-add-line-for-average-per-group), but it doesn't work, I reckon because my x-groups are composed of a single x-value each, for which I believe the procedure should be different.

More in detail, if I add:

```
+ geom_line(stat = "hline", yintercept = "mean", aes(colour = data_table[, 2]))
```

to the previous code line, it gives me the following error: *geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?*.

If I try with the procedure suggest in the answer to that question, by adding:

```
+ geom_errorbar(stat = "hline", yintercept = "mean", width=0.8, aes(ymax=..y..,ymin=..y..))
```

to my initial code (I have removed the `geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.4))` piece of code, because it added random points to my data plot), I get three lines for each group (each corresponding to the mean of the three groups indicated in red, green, blue for that specifical x-group), as shown in this picture:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Those lines are not random, they are the means for the `group` variable in each level of `factor(data[,8])`. If you just want the mean of level of `factor(data[,8])`, you have to delete the `aes(colour = group)` in the `geom_line` part.

Comment: A side note: it's always better to include some example data in your question. See [this question on how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for the side note, I did not add examples because they come from proprietary data, but I will try to add some now.
You are right about the nature of those lines, but there was a misunderstanding: they are not plotted when I add `geom_line`, but only when I add `+ geom_errorbar(stat = "hline", yintercept = "mean",  width=0.8,aes(ymax=..y..,ymin=..y..))`.
If I try to remove the `aes` from this part, R returns an error message (geom_errorbar requires the following missing aesthetics: ymin, ymax).

Comment: See my answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Why don't you use a box plot?

Comment: @rrs A good suggestion (see my updated answer). However, the middle line represents the median and not the mean. As OP wants to plot the mean, I think my first solution is better than a boxplot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should give you the desired result:

```
# creating reproducible data
set.seed(1)
data <- runif(50, 13, 17)
factors <- as.factor(sample(1:3, 50, replace = TRUE))
groups <- as.factor(sample(1:3, 50, replace = TRUE))
data_table <- data.frame(data, factors, groups)

# creating the plot
ggplot(data=data_table, aes(x=factor(factors), y=data, color=groups)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(stat = "hline", yintercept = "mean", width=0.6, aes(ymax=..y.., ymin=..y.., group=factor(factors)), color="black")
```

which gives:
[image]

Checking whether the means are correct:

```
> by(data_table$data, data_table$factors, mean)
data_table$factors: 1
[1] 15.12186
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
data_table$factors: 2
[1] 15.03746
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
data_table$factors: 3
[1] 15.24869
```

which leads to the conclusion that the means are correctly displayed in the plot.

---

Following the suggestion of @rrs, you could also combine it with a boxplot:

```
ggplot(data=data_table, aes(x=factor(factors), y=data, color=groups)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(middle=mean(data), color=NULL)) +
  geom_point(size=2.5)
```

which gives:
[image]

However, the middle line represents the median and not the mean.

Comment: [It looks like](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1259) there may not be a `hline` statistic in future versions of ggplot2.  As far as I can tell you get the same result using `stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean"` instead of `stat = "hline", yintercept = "mean"`.