# How can I set median crossbars to align within factors?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have a data frame like so:

```
my_df <- structure(list(SampleID = c("sample01", "sample02", "sample03", 
"sample04", "sample05", "sample06", "sample07", "sample08", "sample09", 
"sample10", "sample11", "sample12", "sample13", "sample14", "sample15", 
"sample16", "sample17", "sample18", "sample19", "sample20"), 
    y = c(1.68547922357333, 0.717650914301956, 1.18156420566867, 
    1.31643130248052, 1.2021341615705, 0.946937741954258, 1.75576099871947, 
    0.952670480793451, 2.00921185693852, 0.968642950473789, 1.65243482711174, 
    2.14332269635055, 0.30556964944383, 0.860605616591314, 0.933339331803171, 
    1.31797519903504, 0.857873539291964, -0.328227710452388, 
    -0.22023346428776, 1.6600566728651), week = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "3", "6"), class = "factor"), 
    grumpy = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), week_grumpy = structure(c(2L, 
    4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
    6L, 1L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("0 No", "0 Yes", "3 No", "3 Yes", 
    "6 No", "6 Yes"), class = "factor")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))

#packages needed if you don't have
install.packages("ggbeeswarm")
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

This is typically how I graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbeeswarm)

ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x=week, y=y, color=grumpy)) +
    geom_quasirandom(dodge.width = 0.75)
```

[image: Typical plot]

Which is nice because it separates the colors rather nicely. Nowadays, I like to add a median crossbars to further show the differences between groups. Like so:

```
ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x=week, y=y, color=grumpy)) +
    geom_quasirandom(dodge.width = 0.75) +
    stat_summary(aes(group = grumpy), fun = median, fun.min = median, fun.max = median, geom = "crossbar", color = "black", width = 0.7, lwd = 0.2)
```

[image: typical plot with median lines]

Now, what I would love to have is the median crossbars to align with the colors within each factor on the x-axis. Is there a way to do this within R? Or am I relegated to manually editing the crossbars to line up?

Here's is one thing I have tried:

```
ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x=week_grumpy, y=y, color=grumpy)) +
    geom_jitter(width = 0.1) +
    stat_summary(aes(group = grumpy), fun = median, fun.min = median, fun.max = median, geom = "crossbar", color = "black", width = 0.7, lwd = 0.2)
```

[image: median bars lined up but x-axis messy]

But now the x-axis is not the way I want it (However, it would be easier to manually edit in something like Inkscape than the previous example).

I've found some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126843/displaying-stat-summary-within-each-group-by-aesthetic-mapping-in-ggplot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487007/add-average-lines-for-categorical-scatterplots-with-single-group-values) but have yet to arrive at a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is to dodge the crossbar geom.  For example:

```
ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x=week, y=y, color=grumpy)) +
  geom_quasirandom(dodge.width = 0.75) +
  stat_summary(
    aes(group = grumpy), fun = median, fun.min = median, fun.max = median,
    geom = "crossbar", color = "black", width = 0.7, lwd = 0.2,

    # add this bit here to your stat_summary function
    position=position_dodge(width=0.75)
  )
```

[image]

It seems that `geom_quasirandom()` is acting here very similarly to `geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.75))`.  In this case, since `dodge.width` is specified in `geom_quasirandom()`, you use the same `width` for `position_dodge` in the crossbar geom.

*Note: you may want to play around with aesthetic formatting to be able to make the distinction a bit more clear what the crossbars are telling you, but this should answer your question.*